# Dynamically Assign character output of a variable to color

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

Very confused on why the following does not work.

I have a variable State. That dynamically changes based on an output of a dropdown.

For example, State="Alabama"

I am assigning the legend with the following colors:

```
 cols= c(State = "black", "All States" = "red")
```

Which ultimately gets passed to scale_fill_manual

The above produces the correct Legend label for Alabama, however shows no bar/color in the legend.

If I instead do the following:

```
cols= c("Alabama" = "black", "All States" = "red")
```

the legend is correct.

I have tried

```
paste0(State) = "black", as.character(State) = "black"
```

to no avail.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `setNames` to create a named vector

```
State <- "Alabama"
cols = setNames(c("black", "red"), c(State, "All States"))
```

Comment: Its not dynamic though, what happens when the State variable changes?

Comment: @Bjc51192 It is dynamic.  You can assign the value to an object i.e. 'State' and pass it.  Updated the code

Comment: This worked, can you explain the logic to what the above is doing?

Comment: @Bjc51192 The assignment on the lhs evaluates it literally instead of the value in that object and that is the reason you get `c(State = 1)` will name it as 'State' instead of 'Alabma.  With `setNames`, we are assigning the vector with names.  Here, the 'State' object is evaluated to return the value in that vector `c(State, 'All States')`